# How to work with multiple arrays in pure sh?

Tags: shell, array, busybox

There is this machine where only `sh` is available, and `cut` doesn't have `--output-delimiter` option but I need to work with arrays, I tried this way, it works on my work machine, but the lack of `--output-delimiter` makes me unable to go further.

How should I proceed to keep the same results as my work machine with these constrains?

I cannot use `-d '\n'` as it is more than one char, my arraying method throws new lines instead of spaces. Common tools may have reduced functions (as the one who compiled busybox seen fit)
Commands not available in busybox won't be available.

```
#!/system/bin/sh
count=0
LOG=/data/media/0/Logs/MountBind.log
SDID="C10E-14EE"
SOURCES=""
SOURCES="${SOURCES} /storage/MicroSD/Data";SOURCES="${SOURCES} /mnt/runtime/default/MicroSD/Data";SOURCES="${SOURCES} /mnt/runtime/read/MicroSD/Data";SOURCES="${SOURCES} /mnt/runtime/write/MicroSD/Data";
TARGETS=""
TARGETS="${TARGETS} /storage/$SDID/Data";TARGETS="${TARGETS} /mnt/runtime/default/$SDID/Data";TARGETS="${TARGETS} /mnt/runtime/read/$SDID/Data";TARGETS="${TARGETS} /mnt/runtime/write/$SDID/Data";

mountbind() {
    for SOURCE in $SOURCES; do
        count=$((count + 1))
        echo $SOURCE >>$LOG
        su --mount-master mount -o bind $SOURCE $(echo $TARGETS | cut -d ' ' -f$count --output-delimiter=\n) 1>>$LOG
    done
}

mountbind

echo "\n******************************************\nMount output\n******************************************" >> $LOG
mount >> $LOG
chown 1023:1023 $LOG
chmod 770 $LOG
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Painfully.

What you can do is use awk instead. Awk, even BusyBox awk, can do most of what a shell can do, just with more syntactic overhead. And it has associative arrays, as many of those as you want. You can call external commands through `system`. There is even redirection and piping functionality, though it's more limited than in a shell.

If you want an awk script that doesn't take any input, put all the code in a `BEGIN` block.

In your case, if I understand what you want to do correctly, you don't need awk. You don't need `cut` to process the `TARGET` string: use parameter expansion. BusyBox ash and hush both support `${VAR#PREFIX}` and friends. This works easily as long as your paths don't contain spaces.

```
mountbind() {
    for SOURCE in $SOURCES; do
        TARGET=${TARGETS%% *}; TARGETS=${TARGETS#* }
        su --mount-master mount -o bind "$SOURCE" "$TARGET" 1>>"$LOG"
    done
}
```

Comment: I didn't know Busybox has these shells but the script will be forcibly executed from sh, will the variables be correctly inherited?

Comment: @Zulgrib I don't understand the question. You can call awk from sh. But unless you need more than what you've shown, you don't need awk.

Comment: Using your function, the variable $TARGET has the same content as $TARGETS: New line separated values. Tried by running script from ash -c and hush -c, changed bang to the correct shell path.(But one entry is correctly removed from $TARGETS at each iteration)

Comment: @Zulgrib In your script, you set `TARGETS` to a space-separated list, so I show code that parses a space-separated list. If you have a newline-separated list, put a newline as the separator. `TARGET=${TARGETS%%"$separator"*}` takes everything before the first separator.

Comment: Because I do use space as separation, I don't know how it turns out with new lines, the script is exactly as in the question. Thanks